# Crashing Android Application while retriving data from firebase database android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

[Github Repository](https://github.com/SilentVirus27/Expense.Manager)

Error image Shown as above:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.expensemanager, PID: 10677
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class com.example.expensemanager.ExpenseModel does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:563)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:54)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:749)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:741)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:542)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:253)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:100)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:210)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:116)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:188)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:97)
        **at com.example.expensemanager.MainActivity$5.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:107)
        at com.example.expensemanager.MainActivity$5.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:101)**
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

As Above showing error in 107,101 line :

All other require code available to diagnose the code are in git repository in given link.
when i comment out getData() app cant crash data sent to firebase database properly,
issue occur when retriving data from database (just to note im using firebase  Anonymous authentication).

its an Expense manager with firebase database

1. Anonymous login (Work Fine)
   2.Add Expense,Incomes (Work fine)
   3.Get data from Database (Crash App)
   error as shown above
   whole repository link provided

Answer (score 0):

answer is in your stacktrace: `ExpenseModel does not define a no-argument constructor` - just add no-args constructor to your model

```
public class ExpenseModel {

    // data declarations

    public ExpenseModel() {
        // optionally super call if class extending another
        // and some initial dummy setup if needed...
    }
```

edit: checked your github - just add

```
public ExpenseModel() {}
```

above

```
public ExpenseModel(String expenseId) {
```

in `ExpenseModel` class